# How does down_read(semaphore) work in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, semaphore

If we let a thread hold a semaphore by `down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem)` function, it provides the read-only access to `mmap` (list of vma areas), so other threads are not able to change `mmap` anymore. I'm reading the source code, but still confused about how `down_read` achieves that.

Comment: What kernel version you investigated? Linux kernel code changes relatively quickly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. kernel 2.4.26.

Comment: `rw_semaphore` is just [reader-writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock), where readers and writers uses different types of critical section. Read critical sections can be executed concurrently wrt. each other, but write critical section can be executed only exclusively(respect to both write and read critical sections). `down_read` acquires read lock. Its actual implementation is architecture-dependent(for perfomance reason), but is rarely interested in by someone except locks developers.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is:
free lock = 0

down_read() decrements lock ... -1 for each reader (only if it's <= 0)

up_read() increments lock ... +1 when 1 reader finished reading

down_write() increments lock to 1 ... only if it's 0 -- free

up_write() decrements back to 0